# How to get the confidence level of detectMultiScale in "Python" OpenCV?

Tags: python, output, opencv, pls

I was working on my research and currently stuck on this.
I can't get the confidence level AT ALL.
I've tried many commands, such as:

```
outputRejectLevels = "levelWeights"
outputRejectLevels = "objects"
outputRejectLevels = "rejectLevels"
outputRejectLevels = True
outputRejectLevels = "true"
```

but I always get

> TypeError: 'outputRejectLevels' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Fixed. The way to fix this is to use multiDetectScale**3** with `outputRejectLevels = 1`

Comment: Recieving this Error: AttributeError: 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute 'multiDetectScale3'

Comment: @KashifIftikhar `detectMultiScale3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by **@Sax Ted**:

This can be fixed using detectMultiScale3() as following:

```
detection_result, rejectLevels, levelWeights =cascade.detectMultiScale3(img, scaleFactor=1.0485258, minNeighbors=6,outputRejectLevels = 1)

print(rejectLevels)
print(levelWeights)
print(detection_result)
```

For more details related to detectmultiScale(), you can Visit [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html).