# Can openCV limit the number of results that the detectMultiScale function finds as a lower limit can be given by minNeighbors?

Tags: opencv

I want to limit the results so that no more results are flagged by mistake, (I try to identify eyes)
I know that the minNeighbors parameter can be used In the detectMultiScale() function,
but how to limit the number?
(I want something like maxNeighbors if there was such a thing).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64363294/18667225 ?